# How to round a floating point number in PHP?

Tags: php, math, numbers, rounding

Let's say that I have a number like `5.003`, and I want round it to `6`, but with this code I will round it to `5`:

```
$Rounded = round(5.003,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
echo $Rounded;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ceil()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) to round fractions up:

```
$Rounded = ceil(5.003);
echo $Rounded;
```

Output: `6`

Try it out: https://3v4l.org/gY2B1

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ceil()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function.

```
echo ceil(5.003);   //Outputs 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ceil() to round fractions up

```
echo ceil(9.99); // --> 10
```

... or floor() to round down

```
echo floor(9.99); // --> 9
```